# Is it a good idea to maintain 'curr' (End of list) pointer in a Linkedlist program?

Tags: c, linked-list, coding-style, singly-linked-list

- Is it a good idea to maintain 'curr' (End of list) pointer in a Linkedlist program?
  or Should we make a function which can return the pointer to the last
  node of a Linkedlist?
- What is recommended and what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: What do you mean by curr pointer? End of list?

Comment: Yes.  By 'curr', i meant 'End of list'.

Comment: Where would `curr` be stored?

Comment: 'curr' is usually stored in global variable scope

Comment: Then that is a bad idea, because you can't have more than one instance of  the linked list. A local pointer would fine to maintain while adding multiple items to make that process efficient, but global would not be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only benefit is to make adding more efficient.

You could maintain a pointer to the last item, but you should only do this if you have a `struct` that describes the entire list. You should not do this globally as you will not be able to have more than one list.

```
struct {
  LinkedListNode next;
  //data
} LinkedListNode
```

The `struct` that describes the list could be this then:

```
struct {
  LinkedListNode first; //required
  LinkedListNode last; //optional, makes adding quicker
} LinkedList
```

Then you must manipulate the list with functions that take a `LinkedList` and these functions will require more work and testing on your part to ensure the pointer is always correct.

Another downside of this approach is that you can't sub list quickly. i.e. you can't just do this `sublist = node->next;` to get a list that has skipped some elements.

So an alternative approach is to not have `LinkedList` struct and just to store the end pointer temporarily while adding multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a linked list is when **you don't have to keep the track of the last node added in the list** i.e. curr. The only thing you need to take care in that list is *head* (which points to first node in the list) and *temporary* (the variable which is to be added next into the list).

pseudo-code:

```
`  
while(you wanna add more nodes in the list)
                   {
                              temporary->next=head;
                              head=temporary;
                   }
```

`

This list expands from right to left, i.e. `1` (head is 1) then `2->1` (now head is 2) then `3->2->1` (now head is 3) & so on, you can see that the new node added becomes the head.

While when you add elements from **left** to **right** then you need to keep care of three things i.e. **head**, **temporary** and **current**

the pseudo-code for this is:

```
`
 current =head;
while(you wanna add more nodes in the list)
                   {
                              current->next=temporary;
                              current=temporary
                   }
```

`

This list expands from **left** to **right**, i.e. `1` (head is 1) then `1->2` (still head remains 2) then `1->2->3` (still head remains 3) & so on, you can see that the *head* remains the same while adding new nodes to the list.

In the first case (list expanding from right to left) you don't need to keep track of current and updating it as it is needed in 2nd case.

Answer (score -1):

It's good to keep track of start node (root) in order to traverse the list.Coming back to your idea, in order to traverse from backwards you have to use doubly/cyclic linkedlist in which  predecessor node's address is hold by it's successor node or last node is connected to first as in circular form.

To know about 
Doubly LinkedList:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list
Circular LinkedList:
http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/articles/circular-linked-list.html

Comment: They are not asking about doubly linked lists

Comment: I introduced it as an example since he asked about maintaining 'curr'.

Comment: "Coming back to your idea, in order to traverse from backwards..." its clear you read this question as how do I traverse list backwards, when it doesn't ask that.

Comment: Oh..thanks partner.My bad.